# How to delete a similar number in the second panel when clicking on a button from the first panel?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I have such a task, there is a group of buttons with numbers, in the first panel and five numbers are randomly selected in the second panel. How, when clicking on a button from the first panel, delete similar numbers in the second panel (this number should also be deleted from the first panel) and then random replace the deleted button in the second panel so that the deleted numbers never again repeat. How to do it?
An example of a picture.
[image: my image]

My code is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure butClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  arr1: Array[1..20] of Integer;
  but:array[1..9] of TButton;
  but1:array[1..9] of TButton;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i,x,k,tmp,N: integer;
  A: array of integer;
begin
   randomize();
   arr1[1] := 34;
   arr1[2] := 15;
   arr1[3] := 79;
   arr1[4] := 17;
   arr1[5] := 91;
   arr1[6] := 32;
   arr1[7] := 11;
   arr1[8] := 15;
   arr1[9] := 12;
   arr1[10] := 18;
   arr1[11] := 21;
   arr1[12] := 37;
   arr1[13] := 75;
   arr1[14] := 51;
   arr1[15] := 30;
   arr1[16] := 24;
   arr1[17] := 94;
   arr1[18] := 52;
   arr1[19] := 43;
   arr1[20] := 28;
   N:=Length(arr1)-1;
   setlength(A,Length(arr1));
   Memo1.Clear;
  for k := 1 to N do A[k] := arr1[k];
  for k := 1 to N do begin
    x := random(Length(arr1));

    tmp := A[k];
    A[k] :=A[x];
    A[x] := tmp;

  end;

  for i := 1 to 5 do
  begin

       but1[i] := TButton.Create(Form1);
       but1[i].Parent := Form1;
       but1[i].Caption := IntToStr(A[i]);
       but1[i].Font.Size := 26;
       but1[i].Width := 50;
       but1[i].Height := 50;
       but1[i].Left := 300 + i * 50;
       but1[i].Top := 50;

  end;
   for i := 1 to Length(arr1) do
   begin
       but[i] := TButton.Create(Form1);
       but[i].Parent := Form1;
       but[i].Caption := IntToStr(arr1[i]);
       but[i].Font.Size := 26;
       but[i].Width := 50;
       but[i].Height := 50;
       but[i].Tag := arr1[i];
       but[i].Left := 50 + Round(i mod 3)*but[i].Width;
       but[i].Top := 50 + Round(i / 3)*but[i].Height;

       but[i].OnClick := butClick;
   end;
end;
procedure TForm1.butClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(IntToStr((Sender as TButton).Tag));
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `butClick` Procedure and it worked fine in my tests. Give it a try:

```
procedure TForm1.butClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  btn_tag, i:             Integer;
  n1Control, n2Control:   TControl;

begin
  btn_tag := (Sender as TButton).Tag;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(btn_tag));

  n1Control := Sender as TButton;
  n2Control := Nil;

  for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    if Form1.Controls[i] is TButton then
       if ((Form1.Controls[i] as TButton).Caption = IntToStr(btn_tag)) and (Form1.Controls[i].Tag = 0) Then
           n2Control := Form1.Controls[i];

  if n2Control <> Nil then Begin
     FreeAndNil(n1Control);
     FreeAndNil(n2Control);
  End;

end;
```

Comment: this answer was for deleting similar Buttons, but for the second part (if I understood your purpose well, you want new buttons be created at old buttons place, without having repeated numbers, right?) you have to make major changes in your code structure. I have two questions for this part: **1-** New buttons are created in `Panel2` only? **2-** You pre-defined your array items, can they be filled random or should be this way only?

Comment: 1 - yes only in panel2
2 - in the first panel random generation is not needed, only deletion, in the second only numbers are generated in a random way. When clicking on the buttons of the first panel, similar numbers are deleted both in the first and second then, in the second, any random digit from the array is replaced, only ignoring the deleted ones. I think that when deleting a button from the first panel, the array element must also be deleted, and then when creating a random button in the second panel, you need to select from those elements that remain in array.

Answer (score 0):

In a button's onclick event handler, you would want to:

1. Determine the number (tag or caption) that was clicked
2. Search through the controls on Panel2 to find a match
3. If found, delete both controls then
4. Select a random number of the remaining controls on Panel1
5. Use the random index to clone a new button on Panel2

In your code above, you should be setting the Parent of each button object to one of the two GroupBoxes. This will put the buttons in the Controls list of each groupbox, e.g. GroupBox1.ControlCount or GroupBox1.Controls[0] . You are not setting the Tag property for the 5 buttons in the second group, which means you'll have to use the Caption to find a match.  <s>Also, arrays in Delphi are zero-based.  You should adjust your code accordingly</s>.

Comment: Hmm,  A correction: dynamic arrays are zero based, fixed arrays are indexed exactly as you declare them. (`arr1: Array[1..20] of Integer;` is perfectly ok)

Comment: I marked the erroneous sentences as strike through for you. You may want to delete them.

Comment: I was referring to "A: array of integer;" where it appears that he is trying to randomize the values.  As declared, the array is A[0..19] after he initialized it.  His "shuffle" code doesn't take this in account.  But you are correct, I should have said "by default".

Comment: For selecting the next button to add to Panel2, I would maintain another array or TList of the remaining values.  Initialize it with all 20 values and remove values as buttons are added to Panel2 (including the initial 5 buttons).  Then, select a random value from this list to add.  For the UI, I would have a Arrange() method that repositions the buttons after adding/deleting.

Comment: Feel free to correct your answer to indicate whether you generally mean dynamic or static arrays, and which array in the code of the question you address.

Comment: I would fix it, there is only one problem, I decided to go the other way, and I had other questions. Only I can’t leave the code in the commentary, it constantly sticks together. I want to leave formatted code. Advise something how to leave the code?

Comment: @Lex34 Code can be properly formatted only in questions and answers, not in comments. Anybody can improve a question or answer (see [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) in help) but if the editor's rep < 2000, the edit goes into a review que, where it can be approved or rejected by other users with rep > 2000. Even if you decided at some point to go other ways than your question indicates, you can edit and correct errors in an answer (own or others), but of course, the edit must match the original question.